# without variable declaration in for...of is working in .js but not in .mjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

### `index.js`

```js
let rows = [{ location: 10 }, { location: 11 }, { location: 12 }];

for (row of rows) {
    console.log(row);
}
```

Run with node

```js
$ node index.js
{ location: 10 }
{ location: 11 }
{ location: 12 }
```

But why

### `index.mjs`

```js
let rows = [{ location: 10 }, { location: 11 }, { location: 12 }];

for (row of rows) {
    console.log(row);
}
```

Run with node

```js
$ node index.mjs
file:///C:/Users/WF-SYS-19/Desktop/D/walkover/index.mjs:4
for (row of rows) {
     ^

ReferenceError: row is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/WF-SYS-19/Desktop/D/walkover/index.mjs:4:6
←[90m    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)←[39m    
←[90m    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)←[39m  
←[90m    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)←[39m
```

It is working fine for both `.js` & `.mjs` ,
if *row* variable is declared with `const`, `let`, or `var`.[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: I think `mjs` is "strict" by default - add `"use strict"` to the top of the js, you'll get the same error

Comment: Your code does not declare the `row` variable, and it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mjs uses strict mode by default, so implicit definitions are not allowed. Declare it in the loop `for (let row of rows) {` to bypass this.